# How to use uwsgi fastrouter in multi processes?

Tags: python, uwsgi

When I use uwsgi fastrouter, it only run in 2 processes. And when I set workers = 5, the number of processes just not change.

My configure file is as bellow:

```
<uwsgi>
<fastrouter>:3660</fastrouter>
<master/>
<processes>5</processes>
<listen>8192</listen>
<fastrouter-subscription-server>10.12.1.26:7000</fastrouter-subscription-server>
<http-stats-server>10.*:5004</http-stats-server>
<stats>/tmp/stats_uwsgi_proxy.socket</stats>

<enable-threads/>
<logto>/home/chunyu/workspace/uwsgi_proxy/log/uwsgi.log</logto>
<daemonize>/home/chunyu/workspace/uwsgi_proxy/log/uwsgi.log</daemonize>
```

What can I do to run it in tens of processes?